# App Store Query Keywords not working after five days, time to contact apple?

Tags: app-store, appstore-approval

Apple only allows updating Keywords while updating the binary. So I updated it five days ago and added a new important keyword. But still after five days I won't find my application using that keyword as a query.

Is there a chance that they forgot to update? Or should I be more patient?

Answer (score 0):

I dare say they have not forgot, since the keyword introduction into the AppStore is very probably something automatic.
I understand you submitted an update and before sending the update you changed the keywords. I assume that the app update has already been accepted by Apple. You should check a couple of things:
- Do you have multiple languages set in your app? Did you update the keywords for all of them (if needed)?
- Can you see the keywords that you submitted? The reviewers review the keywords too so if they find something they don't like, they may just remove the keyword (another option is that they contact the developer, but this is not the case here unless you missed an email). 
If you have checked these things and the keyword doesn't work some days after the approval of the update, then you should try to contact Apple support and ask them to review your case.

Comment: Then you should just go to the end of my reply. I just wanted to make sure about all keywords were in the same language or the keywords are corresponding to the Store corresponding to your searches.

Comment: The keyword is still there so I emailed them and they told me they removed it in their index without telling me. I asked them to add it again since then I haven't heard from them.

Comment: Wow, that was nasty from them :( First time I hear about this kind of situation. Best of luck with them!